# Period in package name is replaced by comma

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-manifest, action, receiver

1) Whenever i run my code the "." between the appwidget.action in tag"action" turns into ",". What is causing the problem? can anyone help me ?

Before running the code,

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.newstart.practice.Widget" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
         android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff" />
</receiver>
```

After running the code,

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.newstart.practice.Widget" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget,action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
         android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff" />
</receiver>
```

It automatically changes into "," and shows me an error:

```
 Error:(228) Tag <action> attribute name has invalid character ','
```

2) And under this error this error is also shown-

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: What are you running the code with?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to change the `,`  to a `.` in the original `AndroidManifest.xml` not in one of the generated/intermediate ones.

Comment: i did that but it still changes automatically to "," !